# List indices must be integers or slices, not Bar // Having trouble resolving when iterating through list

Tags: python

So I have had some working code for awhile but when trying to get back and do some refactoring, I am running into a ‘list indices must be integers or slices, not Bar’ and cannot seem to figure out how to resolve it.

I am doing a simple iteration through tickers based on certain conditions to generate a list but now sure if its the dates I am passing through or have I am formulating the dataframe.

Utilizing the Alpaca Markets API (get_bars).

```
def get_tickers(api: tradeapi.REST):
    assets = api.list_assets(status="active", asset_class="us_equity")
    symbols = [asset.symbol for asset in assets if asset.tradable]
    
    '''Getting the list of symbols that can be traded'''
    start_time = (pd.to_datetime(datetime.now()) - pd.Timedelta("500000T")) 
    start_time = start_time.replace(second=0, microsecond=0).tz_localize('GMT').tz_convert('America/New_York')

    end_time = (pd.to_datetime(datetime.now()))
    end_time = end_time.replace(second=0, microsecond=0).tz_localize('GMT').tz_convert('America/New_York')
    limit = 250
    
    j = 0
    symbol_list = []
    price_list = []
    for i in tqdm(range(200, len(symbols)+1, 200)):
        get_symbols = symbols[j:i]
        daily_bars = api.get_bars(symbol=get_symbols, timeframe=TimeFrame.Day, start=start_time.isoformat(), end=end_time.isoformat(), limit=limit, adjustment='raw')
        for bar in daily_bars:
            try:
                if daily_bars[bar] != []:
                    df = daily_bars[bar].df
                    
                    # macd_line = macd(df["close"], window_slow=26, window_fast=12, fillna=True)
                    # macd_signal_line = macd_signal(df["close"], window_slow=26, window_fast=12, window_sign=9, fillna=True)
                    sma200_line = sma_indicator(df["close"], window=200, fillna=True)
                    
                    
                    cond_1 = df.iloc[-1]["close"] >= signal_min_share_price
                    cond_2 = df.iloc[-1]["close"] <= signal_max_share_price
                    cond_3 = df.iloc[-1]["close"] < round(sma200_line[-1],2)
                    
                    if cond_1 and cond_2 and cond_3:
                        symbol_list.append(bar)
                        price_list.append(df.iloc[-1]["close"])
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(e)
                pass

        j = i
    symbols_to_trade_df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Stocks": symbol_list,
        "Price": price_list,
    })
    symbols_to_trade = symbols_to_trade_df.sort_values(['Price'], ascending=[False])
    symbols_to_trade = symbols_to_trade.reset_index(drop=True)
    print(symbols_to_trade[:20])
    print(start_time)
    print(end_time)
    return symbols_to_trade.loc[:, "Stocks"].to_list()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, either I have stared at it to long and cannot see the problem, are my understanding of iterating through my list is not correct.

I printed out that the bar is

list indices must be integers or slices, not Bar
Type of bar: <class 'alpaca_trade_api.entity.Bar'>

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `daily_bars[bar]`, what do you expect this to mean? Where the code says `for bar in daily_bars:`, what do you expect that to mean? What do you think will be the value of `bar`, each time through the loop?

Comment: The bar variable is an instance of the alpaca_trade_api.entity.Bar class, which represents a single bar of historical data for OHLC

Comment: Right. So the point is, you *already have* the `Bar` that you want; trying to use it to index into the `daily_bars` to retrieve a `Bar` is both incorrect and unnecessary. See the linked duplicate for details. (Aside from that, a `Bar` instance would not ever be equal to an empty list. Perhaps there is something *contained within* the `Bar` that you want to compare?)